# The application is getting crashed after upgrade the Google Play Service version from 11.2.2 to 15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

The application is getting crashed after upgrade the Google Play Service version from 11.2.2 to 15.0.0 with the following error

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'

Error Stacktrace:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.zzd(android.content.Intent)"
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Fabric reports show 94% of crashes from Android Oreo device

Comment: Your wrote "GPS" multiple times, but I assume this is a type - "GMS" would be correct.

Comment: @LalitKumarSahoo you should update to the latest version your firebase and google services check my answer hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

AbstractMethodError is throw if you try to call an abstract method without an implementation, which is normally checked at compile time.

This can be caused by things like incompatible library versions, but you have everything at 15.0.0 so that should be fine. I would suggest trying to do a clean build (e.g. ./gradlew clean) just in case there is something that isn't being recompiled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to upgrade current version of Google Play Services that your studio uses from SDK Manager.

Go to Tools->SDK Manager->SDK tools->Check if there's any update available for Google Play Services

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Google Play services SDK is no longer updated via the SDK Manager. It is only available on Google's Maven repository (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Answer (score 0):

This is happend because you should use the latest version like below (based on [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions)):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

Also make sure that you app gradle classpath be like:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

If you are using com.google.android.gms check to be to the latest version too (based on [this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
```

Comment: Will check this flow. Have you come across the same crash at any time.

Comment: @LalitKumarSahoo yeah many times, check these 2 links and make sure that your libraries are updated and your issue will be dissapeared

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
As Google recommends to use the same version for all dependent libraries to avoid the unusual crash, but here I can see a difference. Firebase version is different from the GPS version

Comment: @LalitKumarSahoo accept my answer if it helps you, have a nice coding day

Comment: @LalitKumarSahoo, Google no longer recommends using the same version for all Firebase and Google Play services libraries (see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning)